# How to do this Send("Send("$readme 1")")?

Tags: autoit

How to do this command correctly Send("Send("$readme 1")") ?

```css
Send("Send("$readme 1")")
```

So when the script runs types this:

Send("whatever its on $readme 1")

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow,  @Dr. Cookies. Please provide us with a minimal, reproducable example of your problem. And it does help if you put your code in the code environment so that your question becomes more readable. No worries, you'll get used to all that in short notice ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to [the AutoIt manual](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/lang_datatypes.htm), you can enclose strings in single quotes as well as double quotes. That means

```
Send('Send("$readme 1")')
```

should do what you want.

The other option is to use double double-quotes to mark a literal double-quote within a double-quoted string (phew!):

```
Send("Send(""$readme 1"")")
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/merc83 but it gives me this: http://prntscr.com/merdql Doesnt press the "enter" sometimes and the readme dont work

Comment: Variable names may not contain spaces in AutoIt (see https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/lang_variables.htm)... Those `$readme 1`s etc. should probably be e.g. `$readme_1`, etc.

Comment: Anyway -- it looks like you're using AutoIt to generate another AutoIt script? You might want to look into writing directly into files instead of manipulating Notepad++...  https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileWriteLine.htm

Comment: Yea thats better but can you give me a small example how i do it with FileWriteLine? I did not understat how to use it

Comment: Also
`Send('Send("$readme 1")')`
`Send("Send(""$readme 1"")")`
still give me the same problem....

Answer (score 0):

`Send('Send("$readme 1")', 1)` outputs `Send( "$readme 1" )`. Note the `, 1` for raw keys (to use special characters or reserved keywords).

An example for writing into files:

```
; variant one: create new file and write into
Global $sYourFile    = @DesktopDir & '\myNewFile.txt'
Global $sFileContent = 'Line 1' & @CRLF & 'Line 2' & @CRLF

Func _writeFile($sFile, $sText)
    Local $hFile = FileOpen($sFile, 2 + 8 + 256)
    FileWrite($hFile, $sText)
    FileClose($hFile)
EndFunc

_writeFile($sYourFile, $sFileContent)

MsgBox(64, 'Information', 'Variant one was executed. Please check your new file on the Desktop.'
```

```
; variant two: create new file and append text line by line
Global $sYourFile = @DesktopDir & '\myNewFile.txt'

Func _appendLineToFile($sFile, $sLineText)
    Local $hFile = FileOpen($sFile, 1 + 8 + 256)
    FileWriteLine($hFile, $sLineText)
    FileClose($hFile)
EndFunc

_appendLineToFile($sYourFile, 'Line 3')
_appendLineToFile($sYourFile, 'Line 4')
_appendLineToFile($sYourFile, 'Line 5')
_appendLineToFile($sYourFile, 'Line 6')

MsgBox(64, 'Information', 'Variant two was executed. Please check your new file on the Desktop.')
```

```
; variant three: replace text in file on specific line
#include-once
#include <File.au3>

Global $sYourFile = @DesktopDir & '\myNewFile.txt'

_FileWriteToLine($sYourFile, 2, 'New line 2', True)
_FileWriteToLine($sYourFile, 4, 'New line 4', True)

MsgBox(64, 'Information', 'Variant three was executed. Please check your new file on the Desktop.')
```

Answer (score 0):

As already noted, in AutoIt, variables can't contain spaces (you should get a compiler error, if you try)
Plus (as also already noted), you can just write to a file instead of simulate "using an editor".

Sadly, your question isn't very clear, but one of the following should fit your needs:

To write a line like `send("Hello")` to a file, use:

```
$readme1 = "Hello"
FileWriteLine("C:\tmp\test.txt", 'send("' & $readme1 & '")')
```

If you want to literally write `send("$readme1")`:

```
FileWriteLine("C:\tmp\test.txt", 'send("$readme1")')
```

The key in both cases is the proper use of quoting (AutoIt uses two styles of quotes: `"` and `'`)